# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Model.DiskUsage>' to '.Model.DiskUsage'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to check if machineName, machineIp and drive's values already exists in the database and if they exist to update them. This is what I have right now:

```
                          DiskUsage editTest = _dbContext.Disk_Usage.Where(du => du.id != 
                           diskUsage.id && du.machineName == diskUsage.machineName && du.machineIp == 
                            diskUsage.machineIp && diskUsage.drive == diskUsage.drive);

                  //  if (_dbContext.Disk_Usage.Contains(diskUsage.machineIp)
                          {
                         editTest.id = diskUsage.id;
                        editTest.machineName = diskUsage.machineName;
                        editTest.machineIp = diskUsage.machineIp;
                        editTest.drive = diskUsage.drive;
                        editTest.sizeGB = diskUsage.sizeGB;
                        editTest.freeSpaceGB = diskUsage.freeSpaceGB;
                        editTest.freeSpaceProc = diskUsage.freeSpaceProc;
                        editTest.fileSystem = diskUsage.fileSystem;

                        _dbContext.Update(editTest);
                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

With this code I'm getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Model.DiskUsage>' to '.Model.DiskUsage'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?  ". I've tried to add FirstOrDefault(), but then it only updates first row of the database. How can I check values of all rows and update them if they are different?

Comment: You need a foreach loop to iterate over the records and Update() them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

The `Where` in the above Linq is returning an IQueryable, and not an actual result set.
You need to add a `.ToList()` to it to get the results which you can then update in a loop or your iterator of choice.

```
 DiskUsage editTest = _dbContext.Disk_Usage.Where(du => 
                        du.id != diskUsage.id 
                        && du.machineName == diskUsage.machineName 
                        && du.machineIp == diskUsage.machineIp 
                        && diskUsage.drive == diskUsage.drive).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need to call To list(), enumerating an IQueryable will execute the query and materialize the results. You also can't save a List<T> in a T.